# Доступ к приложению на виртуальной машине через браузер хоста

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, virtualbox

В виртуалбоксе запущена ubuntu 18.04, где установлено некое приложение. Как можно достучаться до этого приложения с хоста через браузер. Приложение запускается на порту 8888 и использует протокол HTTP?

Comment: Вообще говоря зависит от того как настроена сеть в virtualbox. Что показывает команда `ifconfig` внутри виртуалки?

Comment: enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0

Comment: Ну открывайте 10.0.0.5:8888

Comment: Не открывает, и файрвол тоже отключил по этому порту

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, переустановил ОС на виртуальной машине, затем включил на первом сетевом адаптере сетевой мост, отключил второй сетевой адаптер. После этих манипуляция смог зайти с браузера другой машины по адресу 192.168.ххх.ххх:8888.